# Using a WCF application, "An error occurred while sending the request" VB

Tags: vb.net, wcf, win-universal-app

I have written a very basic WCF application that I am hosting on an IIS Server. Using the Test client, (From Visual Studio) the function returns an integer; which is intended.

However, my client application (A universal Windows 10 app) is forcing me to use Async Methods. 
The below code is what I'm using to call the method. although It chokes at the Await with the error shown in the title. (System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException)

```
    Dim theService As New MyService.Service1Client()
    Dim a = Await theService.giveNumberAsync()
    Dim dialog = New MessageDialog(a.ToString)
    dialog.ShowAsync()
```

Ideally, I would like it to returnt the value and am stumped as to how to get any further with this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you given your app the capabilities

- Internet (Client)
- Internet (Client & Server)
- Private Networks (Client & Server)

in it´s manifest?

Comment: This worked! thank you, I actually just knocked up a quick command line version and it worked. Enabling the Capabilities provided me access to the WCF application. Just for future reference. My problem required 'Private Networks' to be enabled